# Bluetoothsocket timeout on read and write

Tags: android

I'm designin an application in Android that connects the mobile to a bluetooth device. I can do this, as I open a BluetoothSocket like this:

```
Method m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
socket = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
socket.connect();
```

Where *device* is the paired device with the mobile bluetooth desired. The thing is, this external device is a bit special, and it has different times for writing and answering to the mobile, so I need to put some timeouts on my socket for reading and writing, but I've searched a lot and it seems like *BluetoothSocket* doesn't support this.

Can anybody tell me a different way to admin timeouts on reading and writing to the port on the *BluetoothSocket* class for Android?

Thank you!

Comment: Oh, I can add some more information. I could do this on .Net, using a regular Socket, where I could manage timeouts, and then it worked fine, but I don't know how to solve this. Maybe a different way to connect to the other bluetooth device?? >_<

Comment: Are you currently getting timeouts with this code? Is it timing out when it tries to connect or later on I/O?

Comment: No, I don't manage timeouts in this code. Because I don't know how... Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for reading and writing code:

Writng code on port:

```
try
{
    // Enviamos los bytes
    DataOutputStream dOut = null;
    dOut = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
    // Send message
    dOut.writeBytes(res);
    dOut.flush();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Dialogs.showErrorDialog("Error al recuperar la fecha y hora del dispositivo Nonin.", this);
}
```

Then, reading from port until response available:

```
DataInputStream dIn = null;
// We receive the answer
try
{
     dIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Dialogs.showAlertDialog("An exception occured during bluetooth io stream creation", this);
}

while (true)
{
    try
    {
         String data = dIn.readLine(); // readLine();
         byte[] total = EncodingUtils.getBytes(data, "ASCII");
         Dialogs.showInfoDialog("Mensaje ok: " + data.toString(), this);
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
          break;
     }
}
```

The thing is that I think the writing works, as I convert the desired string into bytes, and it works. But then, when I'm waiting for response, it mixes further responses with the desired, and I think this is because timings.

There's no more code in the middle related with sockets. First, I create it. Then, I try to send a byte String. Then I wait until I receive the answer for the byte String that I just sent.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Sorry. The byte[] array should contain the info I need. I debug the project, step by step, but the byte[] received is not the desired. It mixes further messages with  the ones desired.

Comment: The thing is: after 5 seconds, the bluetooth device stops receiving configuration petitions, and only sends information. So, you could imagine why it's so important to manage times in this socket for me...

Answer (score 0):

There are many Exceptions a socket or it's streams can throw. The `socket.connect()` for example can throw a [ConnectTimeoutException](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ConnectTimeoutException.html). Every method in the BluetoothSocket context can through an `IOException` just take a look at the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/IOException.html) and you will see which exception you have to catch in order to make your program work properly.

Comment: But it doesn't throw any exception. What I need to do is handle timeouts on the port... Do you know if it's possible?